# Symfony 2 - Sonata Admin form field choices external source

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

**The context**

- I need to link my users to companies.
- These companies are stored in an other db (mssql :().
- I have a stored procedure that gives me the list of companies.

**What I did**

- Configured the dbal to be able to call the stored procedure.
- Extended SonataUser's Entity and added an Integer field for the company id.
- Extended SonataUser's Admin `configureFormFields()` with

  ```
  $formMapper
  #...
    ->add('company', 'choice', array('choices' => $companies))
  #...
  ```

`$companies` should contain the company list but not sure it's the right way to do it, and I don't even know how to call the stored procedure from this class...

**Questions**

- How can I list these companies into SonataUser's form ?
- How can I show the selected company name in the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did:

- create a service getting the connection [injected](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) to get companies from
- create a [custom field](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)
- register it as a service and [inject](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) the first service in constructor
- supply the choices to the field (into the custom field definition)

  ```
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
  #...
  ```

Then I've been able to simply use it from `configureFormFields()` with:

```
->add('company', 'company')
```